# The word referring to a descendant of legal immigrants

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word referring to descendants of legal immigrants that were born and raised in the new country and have all rights and opportunities like other citizens in this country.

For example, Hindus legally immigrated to USA and gave birth to children. How do you call their children to indicate that they are Americans of a Hindu descent?

Comment: A note on "Hindu descent": it is unusual nowadays to speak of "descent" in terms of religion, at least in the U.S. Someone may have had a *Catholic upbringing* or been *raised Methodist* or *brought up in a Jewish household* but ascribing religion to genetics is unusual, even controversial. Here, immigrants are most often classified by their nation of origin or ethnicity, and sometimes by language, but rarely by religion (except, historically, European Jews). Thus people might be described as *Hindus, of Nepali descent* but not *Nepalis, of Hindu descent*.

Comment: In the USA, they would be called *Americans*.

Comment: @choster Good to know that. Is it possible to describe Britons of a Nepali descent as Nepali Britons?

Comment: @user128024 See also *[How should one properly construct compound nationalities?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48573)*. Wikipedia suggests *[Nepalese British](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepalese_in_the_United_Kingdom)* and *British Nepalese* at the group level; I don't know what the convention is for individual persons. It's safest to ask people how they prefer to be identified; these matters are touchy, and what is [politically correct](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/political-correctness) shifts often.

Comment: If they were born in the US they are US citizens, whether their parents were legal residents or not.  Other countries have different rules, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**[1st generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immigrant_generations)**" or "**2nd generation**" is what you are looking for (there is some debate which is which), but either generation whatever may come from illegal immigrants as well.

Comment: I found the adjective "hyphenated". Is it a valid word in English?

Comment: As I think, the word "hyphenated" refers only to those who live in USA.

Comment: As the son of immigrants, and someone works with many immigrants, and who has family members in social work who study immigrants, I can assure you that in the U.S., *first-generation* refers to the immigrants themselves, while their children are ***second-generation***. I have never heard of native-born children of the foreign-born referred to as *first-generation*. Sometimes, immigrants who came over as teenagers are known as the *1.5 generation* (*one-point-five generation*).

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "hyphenated" in that usage. Now you can hyphenate to indicate an origin of lineage; i.e. Japanese-American

Comment: @choster, yeah, the article I referenced did indicate some disparity between 1st and 2nd in usage. I have only only ever heard it used the other way; That there are immigrants and there children are the 1st-generation (nationality)-americans.

Comment: As your linked Wikipedia article acknowledges, there's some ambiguity as to whether *first generation* identifies *people who were born in one country and relocated to another,* or *their children, born in the country they [the parents] have relocated to*. Personally, I always assume the former. I think *second-generation immigrants* is a far more common usage in the UK, and it almost *always* means *born in the UK, of parents who were themselves immigrants*. But neither are very "nice" labels, imho.